# Can I get Wordpress to upload images etc via FTP instead of the filesystem?

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I'm installing a Wordpress blog on a site run from a server farm. We can only upload files through FTP (which gets synced to the web servers). Any file written to the server through the web site is deleted after about 5 minutes.

I've found a few FTP plugins for Wordpress, which look like they will allow me to upload files using FTP. The problem is, we need to go to that plugin and upload the files, then go back to the WP post to add them... not very convenient, really.

I know Wordpress has FTP capabilities when installing plugins and themes, but is there a way to get Wordpress to use FTP for the main upload manager when writing a post?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, we had a similar situation and decided to use this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/

w3-total-cache allows you to set a CDN for serving images, as well as Amazon S3 etc the CDN can also be a regular FTP account. We setup assets.example.com pointed some FTP details to it.
When a author publishes a post, any attached files are automatically uploaded to the CDN and the image paths rewritten.

Comment: Interesting idea. Will that work for the same domain? I'd like to put the images in the normal place they will go (wp-content/uploads/) if possible.

Comment: I assume so, if not just setup cdn.example.com as an alias example.com